# Make Iframe cover the full page

Tags: html, css

I have an `iframe` that embeds a pdf from a folder into the website. I want that `iframe` to cover the full page. I did `width: 100%`, and that covered the page for width, but if I do `height: 100%`, it doesn't even cover half of the page. How can I cover the full page with an `iframe`. One last thing, I have checked other answers and those don't help me, I have also tried to use embed and object tags but those don't work either.

The line of code:

```
<iframe src="/static/HowToPay.pdf" width="100%" height="1000px"></iframe>
```

Comment: By default the height of your page is `auto` which means it only grows high enough to fit its content. Apply `height: 100%` to `html, body` and any other elements between your body and iframe to carry the height down to your iframe. If this is impractical use `height: 100vh` which is unreliable on some mobile browsers

Comment: That's a bad idea. A better idea would be just to link to the PDF itself and let the browser sort out how to display it.

Comment: sets the ` height` of both the` html` and `body` elements to 100% ,` iframe` element is `positioned : absolutely` at the top left corner of the page, with a width and height of 100% each at the top left corner of the page, with a `width` and `height` of `100%` each

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this CSS that set the height and cover the full page

```
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: none;
}
```

```
<iframe src="/static/HowToPay.pdf" width="100%"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

We have property `vh` for get available window height.

```
<iframe src="/static/HowToPay.pdf" width="100%" height="1000vh"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using `vh` and `vw` units within a `style` attribute?

```html
<iframe src="/static/HowToPay.pdf" style="width: 100vw; height:100vh;"></iframe>
```

You can check the preview by running the snippet

Answer (score 0):

Pervious answers offer ссs solution but I want to suggest Fullscreen API. Maybe will be usefull

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API

Easy way to use it is `react-full-screen`: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-full-screen

```
function App() {
  const handle = useFullScreenHandle();

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handle.enter}>
        Enter fullscreen
      </button>

      <FullScreen handle={handle}>
        Any fullscreen content here
      </FullScreen>
    </div>
  );
}
```